# Prestashop delivery address in order-payment.tpl

Tags: prestashop-1.5

First time trying prestashop (at a customer place) on an old version (1.5.3). I'm just trying to figure out how to get the delivery address details in order-payment.tpl

[EDIT]
Ok, found out by myself, you have a "super" variable in smarty who contains all you need : $delivery, so $delivery->firstname, $delivery->lastname and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

I using a great module named "[Delivery Automation QR-code Module](http://delivery%20automation)" on PrestaShop Addons which which automate and simplify my delivery system using QR-codes and advise you to try it.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it ;) (your link isnt working)